# Can I change icon position in firefox 4 's add on bar

Tags: firefox

Can I change icon position in firefox 4 's  add on bar, and how?
According to firefox document, I should be able to rearrange them by drag and drop.
But it's just not working in my ubuntu 10.10 instance.

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-add-bar

> To rearrange items, drag them into the order you want them to appear.

Comment: I added an Ubuntu 10.10 tag because it seems like this could be an OS specific issue.

Comment: @Ryan: It isn't, to be blunt.

Answer (score 2):

Context is everything.

> You can customize the Add-on Bar the
>   same way you customize any of the
>   other Firefox toolbars:
>
> 1. **Right-click on an empty section of the Tab Strip, select Customize...
>      and the Customize Toolbar window will
>      open.**
> 2. Drag and drop the items you want into the Add-on Bar.
>
>    2.1. To add an item, drag it from the Customize Toolbar window onto the
>      Add-on Bar where you want it to
>      appear.
>
>    2.2. To remove an item from the Add-on bar, just drag it to the
>      Customize Toolbar window.
>
>    2.3. To rearrange items, drag them into the order you want them to
>      appear.
> 3. When you are finished making changes, click Done to close
>      the Customize Toolbar window and save
>      your selections.
>
> These same steps can be used for
>   customizing other toolbars. See How
>   do I customize the toolbars? for
>   details.

Comment: It seems I have already select the right context, but it just not work for the icons, even I can drag the status text bar on the add on bar. [see my sreencopy](http://www.flickr.com/photos/hileon/5611865143/)